# Python re.sub() fuction error: bad escape \L at position xxx

Tags: python, string, escaping, python-re

```
import re
tc_pattern = '/\\*\\s*proc_1\\s.*?\\*/\\s*[\\s\\S]+?/\\*\\s*end\\s*\\*/'
tmp = '/* proc_1 */datafile="D:\\L\\new_path"\n/* end */' 
str_tc = '/* proc_1 */datafile="D:\\L\\old_path"\n/* end *//* proc_2 */datafile="D:\\L\\Work\\test.txt"\n/* end */'
str_tc_replaced = re.sub(tc_pattern, tmp, str_tc)
```

I want to replace a part of str_tc in with the string temp. But the error is threw as "bad escape \L at position 24 (line 1, column 25)". I know it might caused that python treats /L as a escape symbol. So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your regex would be easier to read and less error prone if you used raw strings - maybe start by doing this?

Comment: if you `r'...'` every strings it doesn't crash